# s3 select and sql injection is it possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible for s3 select to be vulnerable to sql injection, i dont see it myself. But would like to know if it is, and how to do we stop it. With normal sql against a DB we can use prepared statements.

how can we do the same with s3 select.